# In a phing build file, when I import another build file and then override a target from that build file, is there a way to execute the parent target?

Tags: inheritance, import, phing

In a phing build file, when I import another build file and then override a target from that build file, is there a way to execute the parent target in order to "append" functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible: Just use the full name of the target, e.g. `$parentProjectname.$targetname`. Those are also listed when running

```
 $ phing -l
```